# Выбор элемента-потомка от элемента-родителя

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Есть html такого вида (пример):

```
<div class="form">
    <label for="password">Введите пароль</label>
    <input class="password" type="password">
    <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <label for="repeat-password">Повторите пароль</label>
    <input class="repeat-password" type="password">
    <div class="error"></div>
</div>
```

В элемент `<div class="error"></div>` динамически добавляются сообщения об ошибках, которые мне нужно проверить. При этом нужно проверить ошибку для соответствующего поля ввода.

Можно найти нужный `<div class="form">` через проверку `textContent.StartsWith("Повторите пароль")`, но как потом обратиться к его потомку - `<div class="error"></div>`, используя css селекторы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы найти дочерний элемент, нужно его искать от родительского:

```
child_elem = parent_elem.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR. 'div.error')
```

Но тут есть опасность: если на более низких уровнях тоже будут элементы `div.error`, то и они могут быть найдены.

Если у вас цель обработать все ошибки, то я бы использовал xpath - более мощный инструмент.

```
error_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.form > div.error')
for error in error_elements:
    # если нужно, можно вставить какую-нибудь проверку елемента error
    if error.find_element(By.XPATH, './../label').get_attribute('for') == 'repeat-password':
        # здесь мы нашли ошибки, у который лейбл "Повторите пароль"
```

Comment: Спасибо! ` parent_elem.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR. 'div.error')  ` - это то что надо. И совет с xpath, тоже очень полезен.